# Django - OGP Image url preview works inconsistently

Tags: html, django, telegram, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

I've been struggling with this issue for the past few days now and I still can't find the root cause of it so here it goes:

I have a Django blog for which I would like to be able to share links in social media apps such as Whatsapp, Telegram and Signal and I would like these links to have previews containing images of the blog post that the user is sharing.

Following the OGP standard I added these meta tags to my page:

```
<meta property="og:image:url" content="{% block meta_img_url_preview %}{% endblock %}"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="{% block meta_img_preview %}{% endblock %}"/>
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="{% block meta_img_secure_preview %}{% endblock %}"/>
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="1200"/>
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="630"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
    <meta property="og:locale" content="ro_RO"/>
```

After setting up those meta tags, it seems that sharing links via the Whatsapp Web app or the Signal desktop app the image preview shows up just fine. However when using the mobile app and sharing links, only the title and description show up and the image is not being displayed.

After checking my server's logs I can see that the requests for the image preview are served just fine with a status of 200:

- Example of request made using my desktop:
  [Requests made by the desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OyRu.png)
- Example of request made using mobile device:
  [Request made by android app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewSjQ.png)

The server is serving pages over HTTPS and all requests made for regular HTTP are redirected to HTTPS.

Any suggestion would be most welcome!

I tried a bunch of solutions like changing the size of the image, specifying secure_url, not specifying secure_url and a lot of other variations.

Regardless of these attempts, I am still only able to see the images displayed if the link was sent from a desktop/laptop.